# SQL Decimal formatting not working properly in all cases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SQL Server decimal function not working as intended.

To test with sample data, I created a table and inserted values to it.
Then, I tried to run decimal function on these values.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_VAL
(
   VAL float
)

SELECT * FROM TEST_VAL
```

Output:

```
VAL
----------
16704.405
20382.135
 2683.135

SELECT CAST(VAL AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) AS NEWVAL 
FROM TEST_VAL;
```

Output:

```
NEWVAL
-------------
16704.40
20382.13
 2683.14
```

I expected same formatting for all 3 values. But, for third value it returns ceiling round off value.

Comment: Remember that `float` is approximate. Run this from a windows command prompt to see why the values are rounded in your results: `sqlcmd -Q"SELECT CAST(16704.405 AS float),CAST(20382.135 AS float),CAST(2683.135 AS float)"`. Results: 16704.404999999999, 20382.134999999998, 2683.1350000000002

Comment: @user3441903 is any answer from bellow good for you ? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Gordon Linoff does explain precisely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the nature of floating point numbers being inexact *and being in binary*.  But I want to demonstrate how this is working.

The issue is that a decimal such as 0.135 cannot be represented exactly.  As the floating point representation, it would typically be something like:

```
 0.134999999234243423
```

(Note that these numbers as with all representations of values in this answer are made up.  They are intended to be representative to make the point.)

The number of `9`s is actually larger.  And the subsequent digits are just representative.  In this representation, we wouldn't see a problem with truncating the value.  After all `0.1349999` should round to the same value as `0.13499`.

In binary, this looks different:

```
0.11101000010101  10011 10011 10011 10011 . . .
----------------  --------------
  ~0.135             "arbitrary" repeating pattern
```

(Note:  The values are made up!)

That is, the "infinite" portion of binary representation is not a bunch of repeating `1`s or repeating `0`s; it has a pattern.  This is analogous the inverse of most numbers in base 10  For instance, `1/7` has a repeating component of six digits, `142857`.  We tend to forget this, because common inverses are either exact (1/5 = 0.2) or have a single repeating digit (1/6 = 0.166666...).  `1/7` is the first case that is not so simple -- and almost all decimals are like this.  For rational numbers, there is *always* a repeating sequence regardless of base and it is never longer than dividend (number at the bottom) minus 1).

We can think of this as all decimal representations (regardless of base) always have some number of digits that are repeating.  For an exact representation, the repeating portion is `0`.  For others it is rarely one digit.  Usually, it is multiple digits.  And it is a fun exercise in mathematics to characterize this.  But all that is important is that the repeating portion has `1`s and `0`s.

Now, what is happening.  A floating point number has three parts:

- a magnitude.  This is a number of bits that represent the exponent.
- an integer portion, which is the number before the decimal point.
- an integer portion, which is the number after the decimal point.

(Actually, the last two are really one integer, but I find it much easier to explain this by splitting them into two components.)

Only a fixed number of bits are available for the two integer portions.  What does this look like?  Once again the representative patterns are something like this:

```
0.135      0  11101000010101100111001110
1.135      1  11101000010101100111001110
2.135      10  1110100001010110011100111
4.135      100  111010000101011001110011
8.135      1000  11101000010101100111001
16.136     10000  1110100001010110011100
-----------^ part before the decimal
------------------^ part after the decimal
```

Note:  This is leaving off the magnitude portion of the decimal representation.

As you can see, digits get chopped off from the end.  But sometimes it is `0` that gets chopped off -- so there is no change in the value being represented.  And sometimes it is a `1`.  And there is a change.

With this, you might be able to see how the values essentially fluctuate, say:

```
0.135 --> 0.135000000004
1.135  --> 0.135000000004
2.135  --> 0.135000000004
4.135  --> 0.135000000001
8.135  --> 0.135999999997
16.135 --> 0.135999999994
```

These are then rounded differently, which is what you are seeing.

I put together this little [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=76660f13e716ebd912fbe213e6431bd0), so you can see how the rounding changes around powers of two.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could be explained if we extend the precision of the three numbers in the first query:

```
16704.4050
20382.1349
2683.1351
```

Rounding each of the above to only two decimal places, which is what a cast to `DECIMAL(10,2)` would do, would yield:

```
16704.40
20382.13
2683.14
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be of use:

```
select CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), ROUND(VAL, 2, 1)) AS NEWVAL 
from TEST_VAL;
```

Here is the DEMO for SQLServer 2012 : [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=7d933cbbf24e6c24da63a8d6b4b8d079)

Answer (score 0):

first question : why they are not same value?
because their type is different , `CAST(VAL as decimal(4,2))` will format like `##.##` not `##.###` so in your case it get ceiling round value.

Why not use the same type ?

```
 CREATE TABLE T
 (
      [VAL] DECIMAL(8,3)
 );

 INSERT INTO T ([VAL])
 VALUES (16704.405), (20382.135), (2683.135);

 SELECT * FROM T
```

Output:

```
VAL
-----------
 16704.405
 20382.135
  2683.135
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=135de0f88171ebe9a0d3c1b6b118872e)*

or you can cast `AS DECIMAL(8, 3)`

```sql
SELECT CAST(VAL AS DECIMAL(8,3)) AS NEWVAL 
FROM T;
```